Potential Linear Regression Solution


You oversee an amateur sports team, where people compete in contests of running, swimming, and cycling.
You have a roster of athletes that each compete in races in all three sports, and typically there are short races and long races.
You have a record of all race times that have been attained by members of your team. The structure of your data looks something like:

[Table 1, See Attached Image]

You also have a set of prospective new members that want to join, and in order to decide who gets to join the team you need to know what times you would expect them to be able to complete each race in. The problem for you is that not all of them have race times for every sport, so your accessible information might look something like:

[Table 2, See Attached Image]

A. You want to predict Athlete E's Long Run time, based on the other five columns for which they have valid data. Describe the process you would use to make this prediction, based on their own times in the other sports and the table of "complete" data.


B. Athlete F has never swam before, but has times in Short/Long Runs/Cycles.


i) How could you combine the information you have at your disposal to make a prediction for both of their Swim times?


ii) Would you be more or less confident in your prediction than the previous one (Athlete E’s Long Run time)? Why?

I'm new to statical and machine learning. This was asked in an online assessment for a company.
I believe we can use linear regression to predict Athlete E's Long Run time. However, there are 6 races in this question. I am not sure how to regress this kind of data.
Can someone help me solve this question?
Additionally, can you suggest some books or online resources to help learn and practice these kinds of questions?
Thanks!
